# Query to Flatten the array objects in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the below couchbase document,

```
 {
      "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2106",
      "attributes": [
         {
            "label": "Reviewed By",
            "name": "reviewedBy",
            "value": "QA.Praveen"
         },
         {
            "label": "Assigned To",
            "name": "assignedTo",
            "value": "Praveen"
         },
         {
            "label": "Completed Lines",
            "name": "completedLines",
            "value": "23"
         }
      ],
    "hasConversations": false,
    "id": "02efdb67-798f-4616-9750-c80c17c4c1ee",
    "status": "Completed",
    "task": {
        "details": {
            "hasAttachments": true,
            "importance": "normal",
            "subject": "very interesting"
        },
        "taskType": "mail"
    },
    "taskId": "02efdb67-798f-4616-9750-c80c17c4c1ee",
    "type": "task"
}
```

Finding a query from which we can get the flatten document instead of nested array object
I have tried with below queries,

```
SELECT a.taskId, a.appId, ARRAY_FLATTEN( ARRAY_AGG ({ attr.name:attr.`value`}) ,0) as attr FROM workFlowDetails a UNNEST a.attributes attr WHERE a.type = "task" and a.taskId = '02efdb67-798f-4616-9750-c80c17c4c1ee' GROUP BY  a.taskId, a.appId;
```

but this query is not working as required,

The expected output is :

```
{
    "appId": "f1606a90-c96f-4db9-8e5f-9f0b6d2d2106",
    "taskId": "02efdb67-798f-4616-9750-c80c17c4c1ee",
    "type": "task",
    "hasConversations": false,
    "id": "02efdb67-798f-4616-9750-c80c17c4c1ee",
    "status": "Completed",
    "reviewedBy": "QA.Praveen",
    "assignedTo": "Praveen",
    "completedLines": "23",
    "taskType": "mail",
    "hasAttachments": true,
    "importance": "normal",
    "subject": "very interesting"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT appId, taskId, type, hasConversations, id, status, 
OBJECT ele.name:ele.`value` FOR ele IN attributes END.*,
task.taskType, task.details.* FROM workFlowDetails;
```

Please add whatever necessary predicates you require in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.appId, t.taskId, t.type, t.hasConversations, t.id, t.status,task.taskType, details.*,  attr.* 
FROM `test` t  UNNEST t.attributes AS attr 
LET task = t.task, details = t.task.details  
WHERE t.type = "task" and t.taskId = '02efdb67-798f-4616-9750-c80c17c4c1ee';
```

Thanks.